# Injectivity constraints in the Quadratic Assignment Problem

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I've started to read something about Quadratic Assignment Problem, as a natural problem carried by a Graph Matching Task.

Let $i, i' \in \{1, \dots,N\}$ and define a *matching matrix* $y$ with $y_{ii'} \in \{0,1\}$ s.t $y_{ii'}=1$ if there exists a permutation $\phi : N \rightarrow N$ such that $\phi(i)=i'$ and $0$ otherwise. The QAP is defined as finding

$$y^* = arg\max_y \left[\sum_{i,i'}c_{ii'}y_{ii'} + \sum_{ii'jj'}d_{ii'jj'}y_{ii'}y_{jj'}\right]$$

and it is said that the above problem can be subject to *injectivity constraint* (one-to-one) that is $\sum_i y_{ii'} \le 1 \, \, \, \, \forall i'$ and that $\sum_{i'}y_{ii'} \le 1 \, \, \, \forall i$
or the constraint that the map *should be a function* (many-to-one), that is $\sum_{i'}y_{ii'}=1$.

Now is the first injectivity constraint saying that the transformation associated with permutation/assignment matrix is injective? If I have a matrix $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \ni A = (a_{ij})$ such that $a_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$ and the sum over all columns  and all rows is $\le 1$ then this is another way to state injectivity? and What about the second constraint, what is relation of the sum over $i'$ and the map *to be a function*?

Thanks,

James

Comment: Do your questions relate to the injectivity/surjectivity/being a function of $\phi$?

Comment: Yes.. I think..

Comment: did you appreciate my answer?

Answer (score 1):

See [this infographic](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/injective-surjective-bijective.html) about when a function $f : A \to B$ is surjective/injective/one-to-one (bijective is the same as one-to-one). In your case, $A=B$ so an injective function is automatically surjective and bijective. The injectivity constraint should not include $\sum_{i'} y_{ii'} \leq 1$.

A function should map each element of the input domain to exactly one element of the output domain, and that is what $\sum_{i'} y_{ii'} = 1$ enforces: for each $i$ only one $y_{ii'}$ can be $1$ and the other $y_{ii'}$ are $0$.